# How does Mérimée's Carmen mix the genres classical tragedy, romantic drama and picaresque novel?

Tags: short-stories, french-language, genre, prosper-merimee

[Prosper Mérimée's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosper_M%C3%A9rim%C3%A9e) novella *Carmen* (1845/1847) is best known as the source for [George Bizet's opera *Carmen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmen) (1875). The [French Wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Carmen_(nouvelle)&oldid=173576082) about the novella contains the following unsourced statement:

> Dans *Carmen*, Mérimée mêle les genres de la tragédie classique, du drame romantique et du roman picaresque pour illustrer le Mal que représente la passion amoureuse et ravageuse, qui pousse les individus à dépasser leurs limites, à effacer toutes traces de raison et de vertu dans leur âme afin qu’ils commettent des actes condamnables et qui réduiront leur vie à néant<sup>[réf. nécessaire]</sup>.

English translation:

> In *Carmen*, Mérimée mixes the genres of classical tragedy, romantic drama and picaresque novel to illustrate how the Evil represented by passionate and destructive love, which pushes individuals to transgress their limits, wipes out all traces of reason and virtue in their souls so they commit reprehensible acts that will destroy their own lives.

The statement has been copied on other sites, e.g. [Sensagent / Le Parisien](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/Carmen%20(nouvelle)/fr-fr/) (which simply copied an older version of the Wikipedia entry), [Etudier.com](https://www.etudier.com/dissertations/Carmen/62101606.html) and [Fiches de lecture](https://www.fichesdelecture.com/livres/prosper-merimee/carmen) (partially). There is no corresponding statement (with or without a source) in the [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmen_(novella)) and [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmen_(M%C3%A9rim%C3%A9e)) counterparts of the French Wikipedia article. The article [À propos de l’œuvre](https://gallica.bnf.fr/essentiels/merimee/carmen/propos-oeuvre) by Marie Galvez on Gallica (Bibliothèque nationale de France) makes no mention of it either. Searching [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=m%C3%A9rim%C3%A9e+carmen+mix+genres&tbm=bks&ei=CUpCX-lSjtWSBbyvv6gI&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwip-7_xk7HrAhWOqqQKHbzXD4UQ8NMDCJAB&biw=1920&bih=919&dpr=1) didn't result in sources either, or at least none that I can access.

Is there a source for the statement in the French Wikipedia article? I am looking for sources for each of the claims in that statement, i.e. not only the mixing of the three genres but also what Mérimée is supposed to have achieved with it. (I am explicitly not interested in statements about Bizet's opera or other adaptations of Mérimée's novella.)